# Problems with handling files in Python

Tags: python, file, csv, join

Good evening everyone,

I am fairly new to Python and at the moment and at the moment I'm struggling with the problem of how to properly edit a file (.txt or .csv) in python. I am trying to write a little program that will take each line of a text file, encrypt it and then overwrite the file line by line and save it. The relevant part of my code looks like this so far:

```
with open('/home/path/file.csv', 'r+') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t'):
        y = []
        for i in range(0, len(row)):
            x = encrypt(row[i], password)
            y.append(x)
        csvfile.write(''.join(y))
```

Which, when executed, does nothing. I've played with the code a little, sometimes it runs into a

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

The encryption function returns a string and my file consists of 3 strings per row, seperated by a tab, like this:

```
key1   value1   value1'
key2   value2   value2'
key3   value3   value3'
...
```

The csv.reader seems to read the file properly and returns one list per row, y then returns a list with the encrypted phrases. However, I can't seem to get the file.write() function to actually overwrite the file. Does anyone know how to get around this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: You may just be missing a `csvfile.seek(0)` that will reset your file cursor to the beginning of the file before writing (you'd want to do all your reading first, then write everything at the end.  Does it do anything if you write the contents to a new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've open the file as read only.  You need to open a second file for writing.

```
with open('/home/path/file.csv', 'r+') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t'):
        y = []
        for i in range(0, len(row)):
            x = encrypt(row[i], password)
            y.append(x)
with open('/home/path/file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvfile.write(''.join(y))
```

I never like to overwrite my files, disk space is cheap.

```
with open('/home/path/file.csv', 'r+') as csvfile:
    with open('/home/path/file.enc', 'w') as csvencryptedfile:
        for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t'):
            y = []
            for i in range(0, len(row)):
                x = encrypt(row[i], password)
                y.append(x)
            csvencryptedfile.write('\t'.join(y))
            csvencryptedfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Ah indeed, I assumed that since the "r+" means "read/write", I dont need to open a second file in write mode. It works perfectly now, thank you very much.